# Geometric Series of Matrices when $I-A$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, geometric-series

I need to understand the behavior of the following series as $n$ grows very large, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, and $y_0$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
y_n = A^ny_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^kB
$$
Doing a little bit of analysis on the matrix I have (which is a really complicated matrix thats a function of some small value $s$ which is why I left it out) I was able to see that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$, all other values are $0\leq \lambda < 1$

Unfortunately that means that the geometric matrix series formula 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^kB = (I-A)^{-1}(I-A^n)B
$$
won't work because $(I-A)$ is singular. Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: What are $y_i$'s. Are they eigenvectors of A? Or any vector in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll specify in the post. $y_0$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the following values of $y$ are generated from the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supposing that $\lambda_1 =1$ is *simple*, then you should be able to use a common technique from Markov Chains.  In particular, with $W := \mathbf v_1\mathbf u_1^*$  where these are the right and left eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_1$ and $\text{trace}(W)=1$, then

$\Big(I+A+A^2+....+ A^{n-1}\Big)\Big(I-A+W\Big) = I -A^n +nW$

and invert $\Big(I-A+W\Big)$

this is exercise 16 on p. 468 of Grinstead and Snell's free intro to probability book
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your help! By the way, in the event that $\lambda=1$ is not simple, what would you suggest should be done?